# symfony 1.4 : unable to find config file : ProjectConfiguration.class.php

Tags: php, symfony1

I have installed symfony in my local server using their docs, but as per http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/04-Project-Setup I have to change edit config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php. but I didnt see this file, I am using symfony 1.4, how do I change the path

Thanks a lot

Comment: when I generate a project its being created under my D:\, I think it should created under my symfony directory at the end its showing the errors

Comment: I made the settings in file and when I tried localhost:8080 it says --> Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

Comment: This site isn't for hand holding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate a project after checking out/unzipping the core Symfony code into `lib/vendor/symfony`?

```
php lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony generate:project myProjectName
```

will set up a project for you.  Until you do this, you won't have the `config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` file you mention in your question.  See [this part](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01#chapter_01_project_setup) of the docs for details.

Comment: when I tried to create a project it created some files under D:\ and got an error at the bottom 


Warning: require_once(D:\config/..xampp/htdocs/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/
autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or direc
tory in D:\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\config/..xampp/htdocs/s
fproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php' (include_path
='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 3

Comment: when I generate a project its being created under my D:\, I think it should created under my symfony directory at the end its showing the rrors

Comment: What path are you in when you generate the project? You should be generating it from the path I put in my question, eg if your project is in `D:\myproject` and the symfony files are then in `D:\myproject\lib\vendor\symfony`, you should be in `D:\myproject` when you generate the project.

Comment: thanks now I got generated all the files in my localhost, how do I access the site ?

Comment: Configure XAMPP to point to your project's `web` directory and you should be good to go as per the tutorial.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to webserver config, but I got the page without any css here in my localserver http://localhost/sf2/web/index.php/, Is it necessary to set the webserver configs ?

Comment: This is out of the scope of this question now, but I suggest you take a look at http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/01#chapter_01_web_server_configuration_the_secure_way and apply this to your current setup.

Comment: I made the settings in file and when I tried http://localhost:8080/ it says --> Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.